# plot value of candle high at specific date in pine scripts

Tags: plot, pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot the value of candle high at specific date in pine scripts.
My goal is to make a function where the user can select two dates and the app can run fibonacci analysis between those candle highs and lows.
The problem is that it seems nearly impossible to isolate a specific candle in a series based on a date and find the candle price value.
How can I use a date to find the candle high or low at this time?
Any help on this would be very much appreciated!